# Adding a Clear Button to a UITextview

Tags: xcode, uibutton, xcode4.2, uitextview, storyboard

I know I need a UIButton to create an action to clear the content in the UITextView.

I don't know what the code is to actually clear the content in the UITextView.

If anyone has any code for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about :

```
mytextView.text = @"";
```